# Could we use another attention module on the outputs of the attention heads in the transformer architecture?

Tags: transformer, attention

Before concatenating the heads in MHAtt, could we add another attention module with the heads as input to combine them?

Thus, for each head we would get a value matrice enriched with the outputs of the other heads, possibly allowing for an even more coherent view on the input as each head's output is additionally improved by insights from the other heads.

Comment: attention means "how much this thing X is useful for this other thing Y"...  the problem with your approach is that i see how X=head, but i can't see what us Y=?

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you.